# Abort older request when newer one comes

Tags: python, django

My question may sound a bit strange, but what I want to do is to stop computing some response for the current request (the endpoint I have is quite "heavy" and takes a couple of seconds to finish) as soon as the user sends another updated request to the same endpoint. For example, the user may play with filtering checkboxes, so I am always interested in the most recent request (previous ones can be safely aborted). Is this behavior possible to implement in Django? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how it is strange. This is something quite usual, at least not rare.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have this behaviour out of the box, no. But it can be solved using a task queue (celery or other) and sessions. With Celery, this would be done using a task for the computation, storing the current task_id in session, and revoking it if necessary - pseudocode example :

```
@task
def some_computation(*args, **kw):
   your_code_here
   return 42


def someview(request, ...):
    prev = request.session.get("mytaskid", None)
    if prev:
        prev.revoke()
    new = some_computation.apply_async(...)
    request.session["mytaskid"] = new
    return HttpResponse("we are computing...")
```

The downside is that you'll need another view to poll the task status and display the result.